# SQL to Return 0 instead of NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Trying to return `0` instead of `NULL` in the following select without success:

```
SELECT
    IsNull(CASE WHEN TICKET IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,0) AS TICKET
FROM
    TICKETS
WHERE
    TICKET = '2'
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Skip the IsNULL, simply do the CASE expression.

Comment: The value cannot be `NULL` because of the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @jarlh, Thanks for your time but it still return NULL

Comment: Do you mean a NULL value, or do you mean no rows returned?

Comment: BTW, are you storing numeric data in a character column? `TICKET = '2'`.

Comment: @jarlh, No rows. In this case, it should be `0`. No numeric, this is just an example query.

Comment: What happens if you execute your SELECT but without the WHERE clause?

Comment: A lot of rows with `1`. Should I create a SQLFiddle for this?

Comment: As it shows, you are confusing *NULL* with *no rows*, which is two different things. Anyway, so in case of no match you want a result of 0. But in case of, say three records with ticket = 2, what is your result supposed to contain, i.e. how many rows (three or one) and what value(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reviewing the answers and your answer to them, I think what you want is: If no data returned, select 0 else select 1.. so:

```
SELECT case when exists(select 1 from tickets where ticket = '2')
       then 1 else 0 end as IND
```

Comment: You are right. Sorry for the mess and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN TICKET IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TICKET
FROM TICKETS
WHERE TICKET = '2'
```

However, it makes no sense, because the value cannot be `NULL` given the `WHERE` clause.  So, you can just do:

```
SELECT 1
FROM TICKETS
WHERE TICKET = '2';
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but the suggestion still returning NULL instead of 0

Comment: @Khrys What you say doesn't make any sense as gordon pointed out, you are selecting only rows where ticket = '2' so it cannot be null! that only thing i can think of, is that no rows returned at all and thats what you are calling null(Nothing meets your condition)